# detecting object-reference duplication across JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, duplicates

I have a number of files with contents like this:

```
function hello() {
    ...
    element1.text = foo.locale.lorem;
    element2.text = foo.locale.ipsum;
    ...
    elementn.text = foo.locale.whatever;
    ...
}

function world() {
    ...
    var label = bar.options.baz.blah;
    var toggle = bar.options.baz.use_toggle;
    ...
}
```

This could be written more efficiently, and also be more readable, by creating a shortcut to the locale object:

```
function hello() {
    var loc = foo.locale;
    ...
    element1.text = loc.lorem;
    element2.text = loc.ipsum;
    ...
    elementn.text = loc.whatever;
    ...
}

function world() {
    var options = bar.options.baz;
    ...
    var label = options.blah;
    var toggle = options.use_toggle;
    ...
}
```

Is there a simple way to detect occurrences of such duplication for any arbitrary object (it's not always as simple as "locale", or `foo.something`)?
Basically, I wanna know where lengthy object references appear two or more times within a function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about something like LINT? e.g. something externally that can report such object references or internally like looping over the window object

Comment: Some external tool that would tell me "look here, perhaps you can optimize this".

Answer (score 0):

Javascript minifiers will do this for you. Not sure if thats what you're looking for. Heres a good js minifier http://jscompress.com/

Comment: Thanks - but if you run the above code through JSMin, it's not actually rewritten. I guess YUICompressor or Google's Closure Compiler would do that - but I'd rather have a tool that notifies me of such opportunities for the regular source, without minification.